# Type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, error-handling

How to get rid of this typescript error (Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type ) ? i have tried to add any to both of those even thats not helping. Nullish coalescing operator which makes it more complicated, any advice ?

```js
const bookType:any = books.find(
    (book: any) => book.identifier === props.book?.identifier
  )?.type;

  const bookTypes:any = {
    "Fantasy": ["HarryPotter", "LordOfTheRings"],
    "Horror": ["Scream", "Men"],
   
  }[bookType] ?? ["Narnia", "Samaritan"];
```

Comment: Stop using any, it will fix all errors

Comment: @KonradLinkowski still getting same error without any

Comment: I doubt it. What is a type of `books`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski its any (mouse over it)

Comment: You have to make sure that nothing is `any` or will have errors like that

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now there are a bunch of extra errors around undefined/undeclared values that makes it hard to work with.  If you do decide to [edit] your question and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I am notified. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand the request; I have neither downvoted nor upvoted the question, nor do I see how the number of votes on the question would stop you from [edit]ing.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are thinking how i solved it (solved it using Record<Keys, Type>):

```js
const bookType:any = books.find(
    (book: any) => book.identifier === props.book?.identifier
  )?.type;

  const bookTypes:any =( {
    "Fantasy": ["HarryPotter", "LordOfTheRings"],
    "Horror": ["Scream", "Men"],
   
  }as Record<string, string[]> )[bookType] ?? ["Narnia", "Samaritan"];
```